# My regex not working in jquery validationenging

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I am trying to use jquery validationengine to check MAC is validated or not, 
in validationengine, I add custom attribute called "onlyMAC" like this:

```
"onlyMAC":{
"regex":"/^([A-Z0-9]){16}$/",
"alertText":"* MAC invalid"}
```

and in form:

```
<form id='myform'>
<input name="mac" type="text" value="" class="validate[required,custom[onlyMAC]]"/>
</form>
<script>
$('#myform').validationEngine();
</script>
```

But whatever I input for mac, the validationEngine always return that alertText: "* MAC invalid".
I checked my regex here http://jsfiddle.net/chennet/LRfW6/, it looks fine.
So, where I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the example in the documentation: https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine#selectors

Remove the quotes from your regex definition:

```
"onlyMAC":{
"regex":/^([A-Z0-9]){16}$/,
"alertText":"* MAC invalid"}
```

The issue is that you are mixing the regex literal syntax with the regex constructor:

```
/^([A-Z0-9]){16}$/    // RegExp literal uses the slashes
new RegExp('^([A-Z0-9]){16}$')    // RegExp constructor takes a string (without the slashes).
```

Comment: wow, it works, thanks. I was wondering why those original defined by validationengine are working even they has quotes for regexs?

Comment: None of the examples I can see have quotes around the regexes. Which example are you looking at?